# Apache/ModSecurity custom error page

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

I am trying to show a custom error page when Apache/ModSecurity rules are triggered. My plan is as follows:

- Change the status code for all rules to (for example) 501
- use `ErrorDocument` directive to display a custom error page for this code
- Use php in the error page to log the error at application level, show customized message, etc.

What I have tried so far:

```
SecRuleUpdateActionById 1-999999 "phase:2,status:501"
```

and

```
SecDefaultAction "deny,log,redirect:http://some.url/"
```

I tried those in `modsecurity.conf` before and after including CRS rules, as well as `.htaccess`.

Doesn't work - still get a 403 error at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the combination of the two?:

```
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,auditlog,deny,status:503"
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,auditlog,deny,status:503"
```

Note you can different default actions per phase like above.

Note also that some rule sets (e.g. OWASP CRS) also set these default actions, and Kay also need then set a certain way if using anomaly scoring or immediate blocking.

Comment: I had the same question as asked here. The hint by Barry was working for me – BUT I had to add these lines in the CORRECT FILE! And that was to copy `/owasp-modsecurity-csr/rules/REQUEST-999-…conf.example` => `/REQUEST-999-…conf` (note the stripped .example) & then add the mentioned lines, uncommented, within that copied file.

Comment: Addendum: used version 3.3.2 of the OWASP CSP for Apache2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a way of using custom error pages or messages with mod_security. 
What you need to do is use ProxyPass file ! in the waf.conf file

```
    ProxyPass /403.html !
    ProxyPass /500.html !
```

This then allows me to place a custom 403 or 500 file in the webroot in Apache so when mod_security wants to show an error it will show the custom error message.